# Unable to connect to the <video> element in a youtube iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, youtube-iframe-api, web-audio-api

So, I'm trying to use the Web Audio API's [createMediaElementSource() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaElementSource) to connect to the video element in a youtube-provided iframe. I want to collect and use the audio from the provided video as an audio source for the Web Audio API. However, I'm finding myself unable to access any of the elements through javascript (I'm using angular on this project). It appears like I can't manipulate the iframe, as it's hosted on youtube's server. But all I want to do is use the output of that video's audio signal as an input for the Web Audio functionality. To do that, you normally just pass in your video element to that method I linked above. But I'm unable to locate/pass in the video element using javascript. I can find the video when I open up my console, so I feel like there should be a way for me to target it in my code, but so far I've had no luck.

Can any of you help me figure out how to do this? How to pass in the iframe's video element to the createMediaElementSource method.

Comment: Can you create a sample fiddle in order to reproduce your problem?